# Wordpress, storing article publishing date and time in variable

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, variables, cookies

First of all, let me explain, what I want to do.
I have a unique table for every user where they can see their posts, edit, delete them in front end. But when they create an article, it's status being "Pending", because only I, as administrator, can give the status "Published" to it.
What I want to do is to show for users the date when their post was created or last modified by them, and then, the date when it was published.

How to show publishing date I know. Because `get_the_date('Y-m-d');` works ok with this, because it shows date when post was modified at all by any user.
But I need to store somewhere the date then it was modified last by users.

What I managed to do is something like this:

```
<?php $id = get_the_ID(); ?>
<?php $the_last_time="the_time_". $id; ?>
<?php $the_last_date="the_date_". $id; ?>

<?php if ( in_array( $post->post_status, array('draft', 'future', 'pending') ) ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'wpuf' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <p><?php echo get_the_time('G:i'); ?></p>
    <p><?php echo get_the_date('Y-m-d'); ?></p>
    <?php $$the_last_time=get_the_time('G:i'); ?>
    <?php $$the_last_date=get_the_date('Y-m-d'); ?>
    <?php setcookie("$the_last_time", $$the_last_time, time()+2592000); ?>
    <?php setcookie("$the_last_date", $$the_last_date, time()+2592000); ?>
<?php } else { ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'wpuf' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE["$the_last_time"]) ?></p>
    <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_COOKIE["$the_last_date"]) ?></p>
<?php } ?>


<?php wpuf_show_post_status( $post->post_status ) ?>
        <p><?php echo get_the_time('G:i'); ?></p>
        <p><?php echo get_the_date('Y-m-d'); ?></p>
```

As you can see I'm using cookies to store these variables. But the problem is, that it's storing variable information only in one users computer, and what I need is that every user loged in from any computer could see these dates.

Thanks in advance for any leads that could help me. ;)

----------EDIT----------

I tried to create a .php file and there store these variables. Then when I need thenm I could include that file, but I'm doing something wrong because it don't work.

```
//Creating variables    
<?php $id = get_the_ID(); ?>
        <?php $the_last_time="the_time_". $id; ?>
        <?php $the_last_date="the_date_". $id; ?>
        <?php $the_last_time_file="the_time_file_". $id; ?>
        <?php $the_last_date_file="the_date_file_". $id; ?>

//Every time after user modification
<?php $$the_last_time=get_the_time('G:i'); ?>
<?php $$the_last_date=get_the_date('Y-m-d'); ?>
<?php $$the_last_date_file=var_export($$the_last_date, true);?>
<?php $$the_last_date_file="<?php\n\n\$$the_last_date_file = $$the_last_date;\n\n?>";?>
<?php file_put_contents('/cookies/time-date-variables.php', $$the_last_date_file);?>

//And when I publish that post it should show echo variable
    <?php include '/cookies/time-date-variables.php'; ?>
    <?php echo $$the_last_date_file; ?>
```

What I'm doing wrong? Any leads?

Comment: it's a bit confusing. Are you saying you want to display the time when the user who created the file last edited it? Or when the file was last edited by anyone?

Comment: The time when the user who created the file last edited it(not published). And also the time when administrator published it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress already provides a way to get the last-modified date. You can use this in the Loop.

`<?php the_modified_date( $d, $before, $after, $echo ); ?>`

If you're not using the loop, You can query the DB directly to get the latest version of your post. Wordpress stores each edit of a post as a separate row in the DB, using the id of the original post in the post_parent field. So you have the complete history of every edit in the DB. This should also give you the user id, so you can pick out edits by particular users.

I'm spitballing here, but it would probably look like this

```
$postID = 1; // the id of the post
$userID = 1; // The users id for whom you want to show the last edit

$sql = "SELECT post_date FROM wp_posts WHERE post_parent = $postID AND post_author = $userID ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 1";

$userModifiedDate = $wpdb->query($sql);
```

There's going to be a more efficient/wordpressy way to do that, but it should work.

Comment: Hmm, I tried to do something with 'the_modified_date()', but after publishing it shows a date when post was published, not modified. And I can't find any leads how to use this for madifications by particular users. I never worked with DB to be able to retrieve and sort data from there. Could you lead me a little bit more forward with this?

Comment: How much do you know about SQL?

Comment: Sorry, was waiting to be able to try your methon, but unfortunetly it does not work. Mayby I'm doing something wrong? [Thats how it looks](http://jsfiddle.net/uFHzG/)

Comment: It shows me the date of last modification by any user. Not specific user who created the post.

Comment: ok, that's probably because you're using 1. Change "SELECT post_date" to "SELECT *" then try it again.

Comment: I've different problem now. Don't know why, but when I want to test users name and ID with `<?php $user_info = get_userdata(1); echo 'Username: ' . $user_info->user_login . "\n"; echo 'User ID: ' . $user_info->ID . "\n";?>` it shows me User ID: 1, for every user. Can't understant wy this is happening..

Comment: Ok, solved that. But now `$userModifiedDate` returns me `0`. With "SELECT post_date" and "SELECT *" the same situation. What can I do with it?
Besides, thank you very much for guiding me throught this madness. :)

Comment: Ok, graet, I've managed to do everything what you said and it works now as it should, I think, but the problem is, that when I looked in database it seems that most of the posts have post_parent equal 0. Why this is so?

Comment: If a post has a post_parent id of 0, then that is the original, unedited post. Only posts that are edited will have a post parent of higher than 0. One important point that I completely forgot about, you need to be selecting only the post with `post_type = 'revision'`.

Comment: At last! Understood how these wp-posts tables in Wordpress database works. Needed to tweak your suggestions but it worked! Thank you very much, you helped me a lot! :)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you could use this

```
$post_date = get_the_modified_date( 'F j, Y' ) ;
$post_time = get_the_modified_date( 'g:i a' );
```

[know more](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_modified_date/)